# How to test if a particular frequency is significant or not in a fourier frequency spectrum

Tags: python, spatial, seasonality, frequency, fourier-transform

I have got a timeseries data with which I plotted a frequency spectrum and I could eyeball all the significant peaks (significant frequencies) in the plot. But I want to do this for a spatial data (pixelwise).

So, is there any statistical test with which I can test, if the particular frequency is significant or not. if yes, I want to remove that taking it as a seasonality, or else keep.

I am doing a fast fourier filter (`fft()` in python) for seasonality removal.
I would really appreciate if anyone can guide me in this.